# ServiceStack OrmLite Not Retrieving SqlGeography Fields

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, sqlgeography

I've following the instructions here to use SqlGeography types with ServiceStack OrmLite v. 4.0.56:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/SQL-Server-Types

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
SqlServerConverters.Configure(SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider);
```

(not a web application)

Here's my DataModel class:

```
[DataContract]
[Schema("dbo")]
public class BusinessEntity
{
    [DataMember, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Int16 BusinessEntityId { get; set; }
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public SqlGeography LatLong { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve these records using OrmLite, all of the LatLong are null, but there is data in the database:

[image]

My tests are simply retrieving all records:

```
return Db.Select<DataModel.dbo.BusinessEntity>();
```

It looks like there was an error when installing the nuget package, however, there are no runtime errors (I consistently get this error when installing the nuget package):

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' with respect to
>   project 'Services\Web\SO.Services.Data.Tests', targeting
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' Attempting to resolve dependencies for
>   package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' with
>   DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolving actions to install package
>   'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' Resolved actions to
>   install package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56'
>   Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2' already exists in folder
>   'C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SO\packages'
>   Added package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2' to 'packages.config'
>   Executing script file 'C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.ps1'...
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:11 char:50
>   + $folderx86 = $sqlServerTypes.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "x86"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:17 char:50
>   + $folderx64 = $sqlServerTypes.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "x64"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:23 char:46
>   + $cppLinkx86 = $folderx86.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "msvcr100.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:30 char:46
>   + $sqlLinkx86 = $folderx86.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "SqlServerSpatial110.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:37 char:46
>   + $cppLinkx64 = $folderx64.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "msvcr100.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>   Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert
>   the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
>   ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At
>   C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.p
>   s1:44 char:46
>   + $sqlLinkx64 = $folderx64.ProjectItems | where <<<<  Name -eq "SqlServerSpatial110.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
>
> AutoHides             : False Caption               :
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Collection            :
>   {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platfo
>                           rm.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.Window
>                           Base, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase...}
>   CommandBars           : {URL Toolbar, F1 Disambiguation Toolbar}
>   ContextAttributes     : System.__ComObject DTE                   :
>   System.__ComObject Document              :  HWnd                  :
>   6425562 Height                : 1671 IsFloating            : False
>   Kind                  : Tool Left                  : 1674 Linkable
>   : False LinkedWindowFrame     :
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase
>   LinkedWindows         :  Object                : System.__ComObject
>   ObjectKind            : {E8B06F52-6D01-11D2-AA7D-00C04F990343} Project
>   :  ProjectItem           :  Selection             :  Top
>   : 283 Type                  : vsWindowTypeToolWindow Visible
>   : True Width                 : 1785 WindowState           :
>   vsWindowStateMaximize HasBeenDeleted        : False Events
>   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowEvents
>   VisibilityEvents      :
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowVisibilityEvents
>   Rect                  : 1674.0625,283.020833333333,1785,1671
>   OutstandingEventCount : 0
>
> Successfully installed 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 11.0.2' to
>   SO.Services.Data.Tests Package
>   'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' already exists in
>   folder 'C:\Users\cklepeis\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SO\packages' Added package
>   'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' to
>   'packages.config' Successfully installed
>   'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters 4.0.56' to
>   SO.Services.Data.Tests
>   ========== Finished ==========

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing any issues installing `ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters` NuGet package:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication4', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56'
Resolved actions to install package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56'
Adding package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.11.0.2\tools\install.ps1'...


AutoHides             : False
Caption               : Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
Collection            : {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase...}
CommandBars           : {URL Toolbar, F1 Disambiguation Toolbar}
ContextAttributes     : System.__ComObject
DTE                   : System.__ComObject
Document              : 
HWnd                  : 32967448
Height                : 1060
IsFloating            : False
Kind                  : Tool
Left                  : 74
Linkable              : False
LinkedWindowFrame     : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase
LinkedWindows         : 
Object                : System.__ComObject
ObjectKind            : {E8B06F52-6D01-11D2-AA7D-00C04F990343}
Project               : 
ProjectItem           : 
Selection             : 
Top                   : 254
Type                  : vsWindowTypeToolWindow
Visible               : True
Width                 : 2357
WindowState           : vsWindowStateMaximize
HasBeenDeleted        : False
Events                : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowEvents
VisibilityEvents      : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowVisibilityEvents
Rect                  : 73.5,253.5,2357,1060
OutstandingEventCount : 0



Successfully installed 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 11.0.2' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Interfaces 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Text.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.Common.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.Common 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
Adding package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' to folder 'C:\src\wip\ConsoleApplication4\packages'
Added package 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.4.0.56' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters 4.0.56' to ConsoleApplication4
========== Finished ==========
```

If these installation issues persist you can try deleting your NuGet `/packages` folder and [clearing your NuGet cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#clear-nuget-package-cache) so the next time you install `ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters` it will redownload all packages from NuGet again.

To use SQL Server specific types you'll need to use the `SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider` and also specify you're using SQL Server 2012 on the connection string, e.g:

```
SqlServerConverters.Configure(SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider);

var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    "Server=localhost;Database=test;User Id=test;Password=test;Type System Version=SQL Server 2012",
    SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider);
```

You'll then be able to use the SQL Server specific types as normal, e.g. this example:

```
db.DropAndCreateTable<BusinessEntity>();

db.Insert(new BusinessEntity
{
    BusinessEntityId = 1,
    LatLong = SqlGeography.Point(40.6898329, -74.0452177, 4326)
});

db.Select<BusinessEntity>().PrintDump();
```

Prints out the populated `SqlGeography` record:

```
[
        {
                BusinessEntityId: 1,
                LatLong:
                {
                        IsNull: False,
                        STSrid: 4326,
                        Lat: 40.6898329,
                        Long: -74.0452177,
                        Z: Null,
                        M: Null,
                        HasZ: False,
                        HasM: False
                }
        }
]
```

Comment: Adding "Type System Version=SQL Server 2012" to the connection string did the trick.